# Excel like calculations in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Excel if I have say numbers 1, 2 and 3 in columns A, B and C. I can write a formula in column D "=A+B" and then a formula in column E "=D+C".

Basically, I can use the result of a calculated column in the same row.

Can I achieve something similar in SQL with a single line of query.

For example, something like

```
SELECT A, B, C, A+B as D, D+C as E 
FROM TABLE1
```

Result: 1, 2, 3, 3, 6

Comment: You should be able to do that as long as your values are the same type, otherwise you will need to cast them, what results are you getting currently?

Comment: You'd have to use subqueries or CTEs. The rules of SQL say that, effectively, all of the columns in a single `SELECT` clause are calculated in parallel (or as if this is happening, even if it isn't). So you can't use `D` in your `E` calculation because it's not available yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use calculated columns when create table as

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(id int, A int, B int, C int, D as A+B, E as A + B + C);
insert tbl(A, B, C) values (1, 2, 3)
```

Or use

```
SELECT A, B, C, A+B as D, + A+B + C as E 
FROM TABLE1
```